# css section and aside issue in html5

Tags: css, html

This is my css code:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
    font-family:Raleway, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:1.42857143;
    margin:0;
}

html {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yb2sLhox/

I need page like same margin such as header, content and footer.  left and right side margin should be  same space.. like this http://postimg.org/image/ojhkt7bg3/a099ed23/

When resizing the window is working correctly. I think in content part need to change it.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The header, content and footer have the same amount of margin for as far as i can see... If that's your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding `padding` to your  `section`

```
section{
    padding: 0px 30px;
}
```

OR

Try adding some `width` to your section like this

```
section{
   width:90%;
   margin:auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/yb2sLhox/1/)**

Comment: Good luck with further development!

Comment: all the best for your site building.